# Does Update Managment in Azure (windows VM) take care of starting the vm?

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machines, update

I have a windows VM and update management configured. The machine is off most of the time. However, when i need it, i don't want to wait for updates to be installed. Thus, i configured a schedule in update management, so that updates are installed every day at night. (When the machine is normally turned off.)

I was expecting for update management to boot the machine in order to install updates and turn it off after updates have been applied. This, however, doesn't seem to happen.

Am i doing something wrong? Should the machine be turned on for updates? (if update management can't do this: is there another way to do this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it through Azure Automation using pre-scripts and post-scripts. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/pre-post-scripts) it is all information about it.

[image: scripts]

There are two Runbooks to start/stop VM in order to update them. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvDMCK2w6hE) shows you how to do it.

[image: start-stop]